# Giving mutex to correct thread

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

If two threads are being blocked on a lock, how can you choose which get's it?

For example `thread1` calls `mutex_lock(aMut)` but `aMut` is already locked so `thread1` blocks. Along comes `thread2` and it calls mutex lock on `aMut` and it blocks. How can it be ensured `aMut` is given to `thread2`?

here is my attempt that doesn't work

```
/*global variables*/
pthread_mutex_t aMut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  changeNumPrior = PTHREAD_COND_INITIIALIZER;
int highPriorityThreads = 0;

/*function that is passed to pthread_create()*/
void* functionThatIsPassedToPthreadCreate(void* arg)
{
   bool highPriority = false;
   if(arg->someConditionIsMet)
   {
     highPriorityThreads++;
     highPriority = true;
   }
   pthread_mutex_lock(&changeNumPrior);
    while(!highPriority && highPriorities > 0)//this doesn't work
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_var, &changeNumPrior);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&changeNumPrior);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&aMut);//if this blocks, by the time this mutex is aquired, there now may be high priority threads
    //code that requires exclusive access to shared resource protected by aMut
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&aMut);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond_var);
}
```

Comment: Change your design so that this requirement is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just saying "Now I want this task to be scheduled and now this one" is not possible, but some thread libraries allow to set the priority of tasks, so it will be favored when scheduling.

For pthreads, you can do this with [`pthread_getschedparam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getschedparam.3.html).